# iOS LayoutSubviews being called multiple times when a subview resizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

In my program I have started doing all initialization of objects in the init method without setting a frame and then in layoutSubviews I set the frames for these objects to make sure that they are properly set.

Firstly is this proper practice to initialize all objects in the init function without a set frame and then in layoutSubviews set each of their frames.  The reason for my concern is that it is called quite often.

So I have a UIView subclass where I call these methods in the layoutSubviews

```
- (void)layoutSubviews 
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self.filterSwitcherView setFrame:self.viewFrame];
    [self.drawingView setFrame:self.viewFrame];
    [self.textView setFrame:self.textViewFrame];
    [self.colorPicker setFrame:self.colorPickerFrame];
}
```

This currently works fine and all the objects are set correctly, but the problem is in my colorPicker class when the user touches the screen I adjust the frame of the colorPicker and by doing so this method gets called from the subview colorPicker and it readjusts a frame that it shouldn't since it has been modified in the subview.  The subview causes the superviews layoutSubview to be called and this is not what I need.

My question is, is there a way to stop this behavior from happening or should I not use layoutSubviews to set frames because I was told this is a better way of making views programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is likely that your colorPicker class is handling the touch methods to adjust its own frame. Instead, you should handle the touch methods in colorPicker's superview class, and have that superview class adjust colorPicker's frame in response to the touches.

Also, I would recommend doing all UI initialization in `initWithFrame:`, not `init`. The reason is because calling `init` on UIView ends up calling `initWithFrame:`.

Answer (score 6):

Off the top of my head, there's two ways to fix this. You can either move this code to where the view is initialized, either in `init`, `initWithFrame:`, or `initWithCoder:`, depending on which you're using. It's good practice to make a separate method to initialize everything for your view, and call it from all the `init` methods to make sure it's always initialized correctly no matter how you instantiate the view.

Alternatively, if you want to keep your code in `layoutSubviews`, in your `@interface` add a boolean to flag that the frames were already set

```
@interface MyView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL framesAreSet;

@end
```

Then when you set your frames, check if you already did

```
- (void)layoutSubviews 
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (!_framesAreSet)
    {
        [self.filterSwitcherView setFrame:self.viewFrame];
        [self.drawingView setFrame:self.viewFrame];
        [self.textView setFrame:self.textViewFrame];
        [self.colorPicker setFrame:self.colorPickerFrame];
        _framesAreSet = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is exactly what I was gonna write.